# Ionic Cordova Detect app kill event when app is killed by swiping it from the recent app list

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

Is there way to detect when app was killed by swiping it from the recent app list?

I’m writing an application which uses SIP.js (VoIP).

My problem is - If during active call I want to kill app by swiping it from the recent apps, the call on second device still in progress (which is in the call). My idea is to detect when app was killed and reject the call, but I can’t detect this event as for Android as for IOS.

Comment: A better way may be to set up a websocket or similar on the second device and if inactivity is detected for some seconds, end the call

Comment: Check my comment :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can detect when App was killed but you should listen to `pause` and `resume` [events](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html).

So as soon you get pause event you drop call, if you get resume you can redial again

Comment: Thanks! But pause/resume events is not exactly what I need in my situation. On pause app goes to the background and on background my service needs to be continued. So I somehow need to detect exactly the app destroying

Comment: @IvanDomnich hi, have you solved the issue? I'm also facing the same